# Export bezier curve as primitive line

Tags: bezier-curves

is it possible to export a bezier curve as a primitive line? I want to import it in threejs as a visible curve with a line thickness of always 1px. I need to scale the curve and want the thickness to stay the same, thats why it needs to be a primitive line.

My curve in blender
[image]

Thats the use case. I wanna import it to threejs and use it as cad door model

[image]

Comment: What exactly is a "primitive line"? A line of vertices? Since you mention that the thickness should be 1px, do you want to save a texture, because the geometry doesn't have a thickness measured in pixels?

Comment: @rjg The primitives are the default or standard shapes like cube, sphere.. and line. In threejs a line is always 1px (in blender too?). Its a line of vertices yes, with material but I dont want/need a texture. See issue [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/curve-from-three-line-has-wrong-bounding-box/8959)

Comment: You can convert the bezier curve to geometry by *Object > Convert to > Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes that may do the trick. Ill give it a try

Comment: Im actually missing a geometry of the curve in threejs, but converting it did not work

Comment: So what exactly do you need if it's not the coordinates of vertices that create the curve? What doesn't work with the converting?

Comment: Im not having a geometry when importing the model to threejs. Do I have to apply the convertion or anything like that? Im going convertTo -> Mesh from Curve/Meta... and then theres a small popup where im not able to confirm or apply the convertion. Or is it done as soon as I click it?

Comment: It's done as soon as you click the menu entry *Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*. How are you trying to export this to threejs and how do you attempt to load it?